# Add search engine to web browser in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, search, webbrowser-app

In Ubuntu Touch's web browser, I'd like to use a search engine that is not listed in the choice in settings section.
Is there a way to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom search engine definitions in the form of [OpenSearch
XML files](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1).
Just drop those custom definitions in
`~/.local/share/webbrowser-app/searchengines/`, you should then be able
to use your favourite search engine from within the browser.

As an example, if your favourite search engine is startpage.com, you can just download [this file](https://www.startpage.com/en/opensearch.xml) and save it as `~/.local/share/webbrowser-app/searchengines/startpage.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the Browser > Settings > Search Engine screen, I too cannot see a way to add one that is not in the list. It looks like you can only select the pre-defined list. I would raise this in Launchpad if I was you, to get it addressed. However, for now you could add the required search engine as a favourite or even as your home screen, until a more viable resolution is provided.

Comment: From the sounds of it, the best thing to do is raise other in launchpad as a bug and see if there is a resolution. As we should be able to change basic things like this to what we want.

Comment: Send a note to “Ubuntu Phone” team

Comment: Yes and the best way to do that is via a bug repoet or feature request in Launchpad